# SQL Left Join in a single table without duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a junction table with Users ids and projects ids :
Every user can be on multiple projects.

```
id|UserID |ProjectID|
1 |      1|      2  |
2 |      2|      3  |
3 |      1|      3  |
4 |      3|      4  |
5 |      3|      2  |
6 |      3|      3  |
7 |      4|      5  |
```

Is it possible to return, with a single sql request all the id of user who are in the same projects as me ?

For example here, return me :

- user 3, because he is in the projects 2 and 3 with me
- user 2, because he is in the project 3 with me

I tried tu use DISTINCT with LEFT JOIN, but i can't find how to use it with only one table...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'me' here? 'me' means any specific user Id?

Comment: You're right, i'm not clear. When i say "me", i mean "any user ID". For example, "return every people who are in the same project as user 1" or "return every people who are in the same project as user 75" for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a few ways you can achieve something like this in sql. The first method is one that I would have written, just to show you an alternate way of thinking about it. I also wrote a left join as you were attempting to show you that method as well.

**Method #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID
FROM Table
WHERE ProjectID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectID FROM Table WHERE UserID = me)
```

**Method #2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT others.UserID
FROM Table myself
LEFT JOIN Table others ON myself.ProjectID = others.ProjectID
WHERE myself.UserID = me
```

Answer (score 0):

cant think of anything better for now

```
declare @searchingId int;
set @searchingId = 1

select distinct t2.UserId
from 
    (select t1.ProjectId 
    from [Table] as t1 
    where t1.UserId = @searchingId) as projects
    join [Table] as t2 on projects.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId
    where t2.UserId != @searchingId
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple `join`:

```
select distinct upr.userid
from userprojects upr join
     userprojects upr2
     on upr2.projectid = upr.projectid and
        upr2.userid = @me;
```

If you want to, say, count the number of matching projects, use `group by`:

```
select upr.userid, count(*)
from userprojects upr join
     userprojects upr2
     on upr.projectid = upr.projectid and
        upr2.userid = @me
group by upr.userid;
```

Comment: Thanks ! You mean "on upr.projectid = upr2.projectid" no ? With a 2 after the second upr ? Am i right ?